# Tensorflow: how to use tf.train.batch()

Tags: python, tensorflow, mini-batch

I use Tensorflow (Version 1.7.0 and Python 3.5) for a neural network and have problems using the `tf.train.batch()` function. See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/batch).

The dimensions of my dataset are:

Test images (100000, 900)
Test labels (100000, 10)

So I have 100000 test images of size 30 x 30 pixels. The labels are a one-hot matrix of size 100000 x 10.

```
import numpy as np
train_images = np.load("train_images.npy")
train_labels = np.load("train_labels.npy")
```

Now I want to get a random batch of size 100 and wanted to use the function `tf.train.batch()`.

I use the function as follows in my code:

```
# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    num_examples=100000
    batch_size = 100

    # Training cycle
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        total_batch = int(num_examples/batch_size)
        # Loop over all batches
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_x, batch_y = tf.train.batch(
                [train_images, train_labels],
                batch_size=batch_size,
                allow_smaller_final_batch=True,
                )

            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y:batch_y})
```

Doing this I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "my_network.py", line 124, in <module>
    _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y:batch_y})
    File "/home/samuel/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 905, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
    File "/home/samuel/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1091, in _run
    'feed with key ' + str(feed) + '.')
    TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. 
    Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, 
    numpy ndarrays, or TensorHandles.For reference, the tensor object was
    Tensor("batch:0", shape=(?, 900), dtype=uint8) which was passed to the
feed with key Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(?, 900), dtype=float32).
```

What can I do to use `tf.train.batch()` such that my network works? Do I need to use another approach to create mini batches?

Comment: I'm trying to use it the same way but may be it's not how it works

Answer (score 0):

tf.train.batch is deprecated and you should use tf.data for batching instead.

That said...

You should separate your graph building and graph running steps for clarity.

Then, when using tf.train.batch, after building your graph but before running any ops you need to run tf.queue_runner.start_queue_runners() to start the threads which will prefetch the data into batching.